# how to add a google spreadsheet chart to your ruby application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am currently working on a website using ruby on rails. I want to insert a pie chart that I made in a google spreadsheet file. I do know how to insert the whole spreadsheet to my application. But I only want to insert the pie chart. Is there a way to insert the pie chart only?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/googlecharts.

It's not only for pie chart, but it won't ruin your app if you add it. If this is really a problem to you, than you can integrate only the pie chart using google API: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.

:)

Comment: thanks, but i need the data from the spreadsheet to make the piechart. The spreadsheet data is interactive. So when some one sends back the feedback form that I made the spreadsheet and the piechart will be updated automaticly. Is this also posible?

Comment: Get the data from the spreadsheet with this: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby. Then you can make the piechart. Is that it?